# Windows physical server provisioning with HPSA 7.8

Tags: windows-server-2003, provisioning, hp-server-automation

I have a physical server that I am trying to provision Windows to. At 58% of the way through copying files form the Core to the target server, the process hangs with either a samba time-out or an error indicating that %path%\system32\ntoskrnl.exe is missing or corrupt.

I can build a VM on the same subnet with the same media (merely a different profile to catch the different unattend.txt file) with no issues.

I can also provision RHEL5 to this server with no issues.

The buildmgr logs indicate that eventually the job is timing-out. Samba logs show that connections are made, and then eventually closed - about the time that the build process times-out.

Any ideas on where to look next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the OS media was being re-shared on Samba from an NFS mount with long time-out settings on the NFS mount in `/etc/fstab`. Moving the media to a different share point solved this.